# Is there a way to assign display changes to a hotkey in Windows?

Tags: powershell, windows-scripting

I'm a digital artist working from home.
I have two monitors: one is an actual 1920p Philips monitor and the other one is a 1920p Huion Kamvas drawing tablet.
I use the tablet both as a drawing surface and a second monitor, which means I have it in front of me while I work, and I move it to the side when I'm done working.
Every time I reposition it, though, I need to go into my display settings and rearrange my screens. It's a minor inconvenience, but I figured maybe there might be a way to assign this task to a hotkey, thus making my life a tiny bit easier.

I'd like to be able to toggle between two layouts, one stacked vertically and one lined up horizontally, like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G1MKK.png).

I have a little experience with scripting languages like JS and PHP, but I've never touched PowerShell or anything of the sort before. Any help is sincerely appreciated :D

Comment: I've never used the [MultiMonitorTool](https://www.nirsoft.net/utils/multi_monitor_tool.html), so I don't know for sure how/if it works. If I'm not mistaken, settings PositionX and PositionY is what you need to do.  To see what positions your screens are in at any time, checking the `Bounds` results of this ps code should do it: `Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms; [System.Windows.Forms.Screen]::AllScreens`.

Comment: **BUT NOTE:** The code probably shows window info at the time a PowerShell session opens, so may need to close and restart PS each time you run it.